# Failed to load RCurl package

Tags: r, libcurl, rcurl

When I tried to load `RCurl` package, I failed with below error -

```
> library(RCurl)
Loading required package: bitops
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RCurl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/nocadmin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /home/nocadmin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so)
```

Looks like it need libcurl3 instead of libcurl4. So I tried to install libcurl3, but it is removing entire R installation -

```
sudo apt install libcurl3 libcurl-openssl1.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cdbs dh-translations intltool jq libblas-dev libfile-which-perl libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libjq1 liblapack-dev liblapack3 libncurses5-dev libonig4 libpcre2-16-0
  libpcre2-32-0 libpcre2-8-0 libpcre2-dev libpcre2-posix0 libpng12-dev libreadline-dev libssl-doc libtext-unidecode-perl libtinfo-dev python3-scour r-cran-cluster r-doc-html scour
  tex-common texinfo
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libssl1.0-dev
**The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcurl4 libcurl4-gnutls-dev libssl-dev r-base r-base-core** r-base-dev r-base-html r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice r-cran-mass
  r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial r-cran-survival r-recommended
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl-openssl1.0-dev libcurl3 libssl1.0-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 22 to remove and 257 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,660 kB/1,874 kB of archives.
After this operation, 66.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I am running R in Ubuntu 18. Below is detailed information on R installation -

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_IN
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_IN     LC_MONETARY=en_IN    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_IN       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I just checked because I'm running a very similar setup and my `RCurl` works fine: I have both `libcurl3` and `libcurl4` installed.

Comment: I have it running in Ubuntu 18.04, and it looks like I have libcurl3 and libcurl4 installed. If I used `dpkg -l` to check which libraries I have installed. I have the following installed: `libcurl3-gnutls`, `libcurl4` and `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`.

Comment: How can I install both libcurl3 and 4 without uninstalling R?

Comment: I don't know unfortunalty, since I installed it a while ago and as I remember it just worked. How did you install `RCurl`? I seem to have installed it via `install.packages` rather than via `apt`. But you could try and see if `sudo apt install r-cran-rcurl` works.

Comment: sudo apt install r-cran-rcurl is not working for me

Comment: I think you can leave `libcurl4` installed and only install `libcurl3-gnutls`